# Removing DIVs in a jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, html

I have a dialog window that uses a URL for its contents

{

```
function(){jQuery.ajax({'success':function(html) {
        jQuery('#menu_dialog').html(html);
        $('#menu_dialog').dialog('open');
        $('#header').hide();
       },'url':'/testing/index.php/menu','cache':false});return false;};
```

}

What happens is that it was displaying the whole page, including the header, the footer,navigation menu,etc. What I want is for the dialog to only display the content inside the `<content>` tag.

How can I remove the unnecessary divs in the dialog window?

Comment: var content=$('#menu_dialog').children().find('content').text();
$('#menu_dialog').hmtl(content);

Comment: sry for the bad formatting, didnt want to post as answer as it is philosophically same as Adam's... hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't make it work,unfortunately. It still includes all the unnecessary divs I want to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than taking your data and using it directly, get only what you need:

```
// you had: jQuery('#menu_dialog').html(html);
var newPage = jQuery(html);
jQuery('#menu_dialog').empty().append(newPage.find('#content'));
```

Comment: Wow,thanks gnarf. This actually works, after including '#' before content. I would like to rate this answer up,unfortunately it wont allow cause im just new.

Comment: In my defense, you did say the `<content>` tag ;) not the `<div id='content'>` tag... answer updated to include the # tho

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work

```
$("#menu_dialog").children().not("content").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adam, but it only rendered a blank dialog window for some reason...

Comment: For the same reason that gnarf's solution also needed the `#`: `content` is an id, not an element.